# Very slow update without cte

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

This query lasts about 30 sec:

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT t.id, to_json (row) json
FROM public.test t, LATERAL (SELECT * FROM public.test2 t2 WHERE t.id = t2.test_id) row)
UPDATE test t
SET json = cte.json
FROM cte
WHERE cte.id = t.id

"Update on test t  (cost=55185.61..96669.49 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=26952.797..26952.804 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=55185.61..96669.49 rows=150572 width=50) (actual time=1415.264..4256.365 rows=150571 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: (t_1.id = t2.test_id)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on test t_1  (cost=0.00..28237.36 rows=545736 width=14) (actual time=0.026..349.467 rows=355580 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=50068.46..50068.46 rows=150572 width=150) (actual time=1359.280..1359.285 rows=150571 loops=1)"
"              Buckets: 32768  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 3717kB"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=10007.87..50068.46 rows=150572 width=150) (actual time=339.426..1191.612 rows=150571 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (t.id = t2.test_id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on test t  (cost=0.00..28237.36 rows=545736 width=14) (actual time=0.015..492.247 rows=355580 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=5184.72..5184.72 rows=150572 width=136) (actual time=225.551..225.553 rows=150571 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 32768  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 3420kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on test2 t2  (cost=0.00..5184.72 rows=150572 width=136) (actual time=0.017..79.663 rows=150572 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.931 ms"
"Execution Time: 26954.723 ms"
```

Another query without cte lasts too much time(still waiting to complete):

```
UPDATE test t
SET json = (SELECT to_json(row) FROM (SELECT * FROM test2 t2 WHERE t.id = t2.test_id LIMIT 1) row)
```

I want to create json of each row in test2 and update test table with it. Why 1st query is better than 2nd? How to write it without **LATERAL**?

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   json TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE test2(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  test_id INTEGER,
  a TEXT,
  b TEXT,
  c TEXT,
  d TEXT,
  e TEXT,
  f TEXT,
  g TEXT,
  h TEXT,
  i TEXT,
  j TEXT,
  k TEXT,
  l TEXT,
  m TEXT
);
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to tell without knowing the schema or seeing the execution plan.

Comment: I don't have execution plan of 2nd query because it has not been finished yet. I'm uploading schema now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are joining the target table multiple times with the second table.

One time is enough:

```
UPDATE test t
    SET json = to_json(t2)
FROM public.test2 as t2
WHERE t2.test_id = t.id;
```

If you want to exclude some columns from the JSON, use `jsonb` (which is the recommended data type for JSON anyway):

```
UPDATE test t
    SET json = to_jsonb(t2) - 'a' - 'b'
FROM public.test2 as t2
WHERE t2.test_id = t.id;
```

If you want to rename some columns you can use a derived table:

```
UPDATE test t
    SET json = to_json(t2)
FROM (
  select test_id, 
         a as xyz, 
         b as abc
  from public.test2 
) as as t2
WHERE t2.test_id = t.id;
```

Comment: In my query I can replace SELECT * with SELECT a as "xyz" ....
How to do it with your query?
Supposing that I'd like custom names in json.

Comment: There is no need for multiple, nested selects here. Or even just a `select *`

Comment: Can't exclude or rename some columns bro `UPDATE test t
    SET json = to_json(t2.a  as "xyz", t2.b as "ABC")
FROM public.test2 as t2
WHERE t2.test_id = t.id;`

Comment: Should I use another json function to get custom json?

Comment: Well, that requirement was not part of your question. See my edit